# Cannot deactivate protrusion locally

Tags: xetex, protrusion

I do some comparision of typesetting tools and encountered the following issue in XeLaTeX (TeXLive 2013 version). 
I use two same text boxes but with different protrusion settings (transparent text, one placed above the other). While the second box behaves as expected, the first one, using the same commands, doesn't - the protrusion seems to be applied even it is disabled...

Is there any fault from my side? I am rather newbie in XeLaTeX...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,microtype,pgf,lipsum}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\setromanfont {Palatino Linotype}

\newcommand{\tufte}{We thrive in information thick worlds because of our marvelous and everyday capacity to select, edit, single out, structure, highlight, group, pair, merge, harmonize, synthesize, focus, organize, condense, reduce, boil down, choose, categorize, catalog, classify, list, abstract, scan, look into, idealize, isolate, discriminate, distinguish, screen, pigeonhole, pick over, sort, integrate, blend, inspect, filter, lump, skip, smooth, chunk, average, approximate, cluster, aggregate, outline, summarize, itemize, review, dip into, flip through, browse, glance into, leaf through, skim, refine, enumerate, glean, synopsize, winnow the wheat from the chaff and separate the sheep from the goats.}

\begin{document}

{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.6}
\begin{textblock}{133}(10,10)
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
{\color{red}\tufte}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{133}(10,10)
\tufte
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{133}(10,80)
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
{\color{red}\lipsum[1]}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{133}(10,80)
\lipsum[1]
\end{textblock}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the lines `\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}` and everything will be ok. Protrusion is set by default to true and inside an environment (`textblock`) everything is local.